# Self join not including children (entity framework 4.0)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am creating a sort of family tree in entity framework 4.0. I have come across an issue where the Entity Framework is only loading the immediate children. It does not load the children of the children even though i have an `include` specified.

For example, this is my query :-

```
public IQueryable<TreeMember> GetTreeMembers(int userId)
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.TreeMembers.Include("RelatedTreeMembers").Where(u => u.UserId == userId && u.RelatedTreeMemberId == null);
        }
```

This would load the 1st level of children. But it does not load the children of the children. If i have to include children of the children, i have to write :-

```
public IQueryable<TreeMember> GetTreeMembers(int userId)
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.TreeMembers.Include("RelatedTreeMembers.RelatedTreeMembers").Where(u => u.UserId == userId && u.RelatedTreeMemberId == null);
        }
```

This is quickly getting to be frustrating because i don't know how many times should i have to write this `RelatedTreeMembers` as a family tree can extend upto N level. How do i get past this issue? If my question is not clear please let me know.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using Code-First, Model-First, or Database-First?  What version of SQL Server are you using?  This may have to be accomplished with a recursive CTE or hierarchyId.

Comment: @Anon :- I have my database and i create model from it. Sql Server version is 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how EF works. You want to define recursive (hierarchical) query which is not possible with eager loading in EF. You always have specify exactly which navigation properties you want to load - obviously in this scenario you can't because you don't know how deep is your recursion.

I like the idea @Magnus suggested with CTE but I would not use DB View. I would use stored procedure. The reason is that you already have entity TreeMember mapped to a table. If you define the view you will not be able to map it to the same entity type. You will need new entity for the view. If you use stored procedure you can map its result to already existing entity type.

Another way is to use lazy loading.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka :- Thanks i will try CTE. I did not understand what do you mean by lazy loading. Lazy loading is already enabled in my .edmx. What else do i have to do? I am using Silverlight. So, do i have to make another request again to retrieve relatedTreeMembers?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka :- I have created a storedprocedure using CTE but i can't find the storeprocedure in my object context. I have updated my .edmx also but still no luck. I think there should be a function in my objectContext by the name of stored procedure but it is not showing up for some reason. However in my edmx i do find this :-

Comment: <Function Name="spGetTreeMembers" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
          <Parameter Name="UserId" Type="int" Mode="In" />
        </Function>

Comment: Getting all the children using lazy loading would mean one DB call for every node level.

Comment: @Kar Cheng - Did you follow this approach when you added stored procedur to model? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896279.aspx It looks like you have only added stored procedure from DB but you also need FunctionImport element in your CSDL to map .net operation to that stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Write a view with a recursive CTE and than use that with Linq.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx